# Test Kitchen Chef Zero Use Sudo to create root_path

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm trying to match Chef zero with what's actually used on my Chef server by setting the root_path to `/etc/chef` from the default `/tmp/kitchen`. After Chef is installed I get the following error:

```
Setting up chef (12.22.1-1) ...
Thank you for installing Chef!
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/chef’: Permission denied
```

I've added `sudo: true` to the platform and suite but I'm still getting this error. How do I let kitchen create `/etc/chef` with the Vagrant driver and Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a confusion here...

> [chef-zero](https://github.com/chef/chef-zero) is in-memory chef server that can be useful for chef Client testing and chef-solo-like tasks that require a full chef server

thus, chef zero does not need all kinds of directories as chef server does.

if i understood your question in correctly (what are you trying to achieve and why would you like to do it), please update your question and i will update the answer.